# Reading Excel sheet with Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, gradle, try-catch

This is the program i tried to write and execute myself with the help of this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mrtw7NvMQvw&ab_channel=fun2learn

Eclipse; jdk-19; Referenced Libraries:

commons-collection4-4.4.jar
commons-collections4-4.4-javadoc.jar
commons-collections4-4.4-sources.jar
commons-compress-1.22.jar
poi-5.2.3.jar
poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar
poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3.jar
xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar

also tried the poi 5.2.2 (because i read about that some of it didnt work in 5.2.3 connected with Excel)

CODE:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.print.DocFlavor.READER;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class MainExcel {

    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            

// Variable to store data from excel file
            ArrayList<Integer> serial = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    
            // Opening the excel file using pop-up window
            JFileChooser openFilechooser = new JFileChooser();
            openFilechooser.setDialogTitle("Open File");
            openFilechooser.removeChoosableFileFilter(openFilechooser.getFileFilter());
            FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel File (.xlsx)", "xlsx");
            openFilechooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    
            if (openFilechooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    
                File inputFile = openFilechooser.getSelectedFile();
                try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
    


    /* i think this is the row with my problem, yet i dont know how to fix it */                    XSSFWorkbook importedfile = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
                    XSSFSheet sheet1 = importedfile.getSheetAt(0);
    
                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet1.iterator();
                    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    
                        Row row = rowIterator.next();
                        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
    
                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                            if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
    
                                headers.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            } else {
    
                                if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0) {
    
                                    serial.add((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
    
                                    name.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                } else if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 2) {
    
                                    result.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        importedfile.close();
                        in.close();
                        System.out.println("Excel File is read succesffully!");
                        System.out.println("\n\n");
                        System.out.println("List of serial no. is: " + serial);
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("List fo students name is: " + name);
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("List of students results is: " + result);
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(READER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
    at MainExcel.main(MainExcel.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Bascially this program is there to simply test reading a Excel

```
XSSFWorkbook importedfile = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
```

im not sure what this row requires of me, it wanted catch etc and i tried many different variations to put a catch etc. yet sadly none of those worked :(

changes:
added Gradle (still no idea how that works)
Logger.getLogger(ReadExcel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); -> Logger.getLogger(READER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
its suppose to be "ReadExcel" but that way i cant make the program run at all!

Comment: Something that you use seems to require Apache Commons IO and it's not on your classpath. Usually the best way to handle dependencies like this is to use a build system that handles (downloads, ...) dependencies for you, such as Gradle or Maven.

Comment: Hi Joachim Sauer, thank you for your quick response!
when ever i add something like:
import org.apache.common.*
it will just remove it (autoformatting i think) (Eclipse)

Comment: The problem is not lack of `import` statements in your Java source (you only need those when you *directly* reference a class in your source code). The problem is that a library (a .jar file) is missing on your classpath. The video seems to pick a couple of relevant libraries wihout explaining why those ones specifically and you are using a different POI version. The missing jar file is probably somewhere in the `lib/` folder of the POI distribution you downloaded. Just add that as a dependency just like the others (and think about starting to use something like Gradle in the long run).